# How to embed an closed source software UI into Qt window

Tags: c++, qt

I intend to develop a desktop application with **Qt** in windows platform. And in my application, I need to use the functions of another closed source software, so I'm trying to embed the user interface of that software into my Qt window just like the picture below shows.
[image]

Is there anyone knows the solution?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Depending on the application, some may have an API available that might allow you to use their functionality but without giving access to their source code

Comment: The circumstance I describe is that we don't have an API available or access to source code. And what to do on this condition?

Comment: Do you mean something like ActiveX?

Comment: For which platform(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a code solution in the Qt Project github which shows a version of what you want to do: [Qtwinmigrate](https://github.com/qtproject/qt-solutions/tree/master/qtwinmigrate/src). Embedding other applications is always notoriously difficult to achieve, and always somewhat flakey. If you're trying to integrate Skype into your application then they actually do provide a C++ interface you can use.